# jBoss-7.1.1 could not be started - remaining in starting/synchronizing

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss7.x

I got a problem with my jBoss-7.1.1 on my JEE application.
When i try to start the server, the status of the server remains in "Starting/Synchronizing".
During this procedure, i can access the server on localhost:8080. (Even if the status still is on starting..).
After a few minutes, i get the error "Server has encountered a problem, failed to start jBoss-Server" and the server goes on the status "Stopped/Synchronized". I already took a look at the server.log file, but wasn't able to fix this problem.
Here is the above mentioned log file:

```
14:21:36,030 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem  
14:21:36,042 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.  
14:21:36,052 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem  
14:21:36,077 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension  
14:21:36,095 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final  
14:21:36,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem  
14:21:36,116 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)  
14:21:36,142 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem  
14:21:36,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service  
14:21:36,274 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)  
14:21:36,275 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]  
14:21:36,609 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA  
14:21:37,075 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "crm.war"  
14:21:37,083 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory c:\jBoss\standalone\deployments  
14:21:37,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found crm.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called crm.war.dodeploy  
14:21:37,134 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost:4447  
14:21:37,152 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-8080  
14:21:37,243 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on /localhost:9999  
14:21:37,383 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]  
14:21:39,482 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name   'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.ConfigurableArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.spi.Configurable'  
14:21:39,483 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name  'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.GenericArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.GenericArchive'  
14:21:39,484 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.jar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.GenericArchive'  
14:21:39,485 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=UNKNOWN' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.GenericArchive'  
14:21:39,486 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.serialization.ZipSerializableViewImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.serialization.SerializableView'  
14:21:39,487 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.spec.JavaArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive'  
14:21:39,488 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.jar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive'  
14:21:39,488 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=ZIP' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive'  
14:21:39,489 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.tar.TarExporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.TarExporter'  
14:21:39,490 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.tar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.TarExporter'  
14:21:39,491 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.zip.ZipImporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.ZipImporter'  
14:21:39,492 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.jar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.ZipImporter'  
14:21:39,493 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.tar.TarImporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.TarImporter'  
14:21:39,494 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.tar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.TarImporter'  
14:21:39,495 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.spec.WebArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive'  
14:21:39,496 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.war' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive'  
14:21:39,497 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=ZIP' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive'  
14:21:39,498 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.tar.TarGzExporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.TarGzExporter'  
14:21:39,500 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.tar.gz' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.TarGzExporter'  
14:21:39,501 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.serialization.ZipSerializableViewImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.serialization.ZipSerializableView'  
14:21:39,503 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.ExplodedImporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.ExplodedImporter'  
14:21:39,504 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.spec.ResourceAdapterArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.ResourceAdapterArchive'  
14:21:39,505 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.rar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.ResourceAdapterArchive'  
14:21:39,506 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=ZIP' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.ResourceAdapterArchive'  
14:21:39,507 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.ExplodedExporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.ExplodedExporter'  
14:21:39,508 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.spec.EnterpriseArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.EnterpriseArchive'  
14:21:39,509 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.ear' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.EnterpriseArchive'  
14:21:39,510 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=ZIP' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.EnterpriseArchive'  
14:21:39,511 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.tar.TarGzImporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.TarGzImporter'  
14:21:39,512 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.tar.gz' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.TarGzImporter'  
14:21:39,513 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.zip.ZipExporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.ZipExporter'  
14:21:39,515 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implClass=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenBuilderImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.MavenDependencyResolver'  
14:21:39,798 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for primary  
14:21:40,053 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment crm.war  
14:21:40,076 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named ContractServiceBean in deployment unit deployment "crm.war" are as follows:  

java:global/crm/ContractServiceBean!info.crm.services.ContractService  
java:app/crm/ContractServiceBean!info.crm.services.ContractService  
java:module/ContractServiceBean!info.crm.services.ContractService  
java:global/crm/ContractServiceBean  
java:app/crm/ContractServiceBean  
java:module/ContractServiceBean  

14:21:40,077 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named CustomerServiceBean in deployment unit deployment "crm.war" are as follows:  

java:global/crm/CustomerServiceBean!info.crm.services.CustomerService  
java:app/crm/CustomerServiceBean!info.crm.services.CustomerService  
java:module/CustomerServiceBean!info.crm.services.CustomerService  
java:global/crm/CustomerServiceBean  
java:app/crm/CustomerServiceBean  
java:module/CustomerServiceBean  

14:21:40,079 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named ContactPersonServiceBean in deployment unit deployment "crm.war" are as follows:  

java:global/crm/ContactPersonServiceBean!info.crm.services.ContactPersonService  
java:app/crm/ContactPersonServiceBean!info.crm.services.ContactPersonService  
java:module/ContactPersonServiceBean!info.crm.services.ContactPersonService  
java:global/crm/ContactPersonServiceBean  
java:app/crm/ContactPersonServiceBean  
java:module/ContactPersonServiceBean  

>14:21:40,575 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: crm.war  
14:21:40,624 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000900 1.1.5 (AS71)  
14:21:40,695 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [jboss/datasources/crmDS]  
14:21:40,696 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'crm.war#primary'  
14:21:40,873 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}  
14:21:40,881 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}  
14:21:40,884 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found  
14:21:40,888 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist  
14:21:40,916 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [  
    name: primary  
    ...]  
14:21:41,244 INFO [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider  
14:21:43,682 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect  
14:21:43,688 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work  
14:21:43,692 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4  
14:21:43,702 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory  
14:21:43,707 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  
14:21:43,744 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final  
14:21:44,196 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update  
14:21:44,197 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata  
14:21:44,210 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000396: Updating schema  
14:21:44,235 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000261: Table found: CRM.PUBLIC.CONTACTPERSON  
14:21:44,235 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000037: Columns: [id, phone, fax, email, lastname, firstname, salutation, customer_id, mobile]  
14:21:44,236 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk4e7b4375bf149ed7]  
14:21:44,237 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000126: Indexes: [fk4e7b4375bf149ed7_index_f, primary_key_f]  
14:21:44,247 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000261: Table found: CRM.PUBLIC.CONTRACT  
14:21:44,248 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000037: Columns: [id, signdate, referencenumber, customer_id]  
14:21:44,249 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fke20f7532bf149ed7]  
14:21:44,250 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000126: Indexes: [fke20f7532bf149ed7_index_c, primary_key_c]  
14:21:44,260 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000261: Table found: CRM.PUBLIC.CONTRACTPRODUCT  
14:21:44,261 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000037: Columns: [amount, id, product_id, contract_id]  
14:21:44,262 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk354135d6436a257, fk354135dbddc5dd]  
14:21:44,263 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000126: Indexes: [fk354135d6436a257_index_1, fk354135dbddc5dd_index_1, primary_key_1]  
14:21:44,273 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000261: Table found: CRM.PUBLIC.CUSTOMER  
14:21:44,274 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000037: Columns: [id, phone, companyname2, email, companyname3, name, companyname1]  
14:21:44,275 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
14:21:44,276 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000126: Indexes: [primary_key_5]  
14:21:44,290 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000261: Table found: CRM.PUBLIC.PRODUCT  
14:21:44,291 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000037: Columns: [id, count, contractproduct_id, productdescription, productname]  
14:21:44,292 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk50c664cfcf083fd]  
14:21:44,293 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000126: Indexes: [primary_key_18, fk50c664cfcf083fd_index_1]  
14:21:44,295 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000232: Schema update complete  
14:21:44,472 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment crm.war  
14:21:46,159 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-5) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/crm'  
14:21:49,064 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (MSC service thread 1-5) Running on PrimeFaces 4.0  
14:21:49,065 INFO  [org.omnifaces.VersionLoggerEventListener] (MSC service thread 1-5) Using OmniFaces version 1.6.3  
14:21:49,123 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /crm  
14:21:49,150 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "crm.war"  
14:21:50,224 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on /localhost:9990

14:21:50,225 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 16619ms - Started 241 of 318 services (76 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: Your server log indicates the server has started fine. Where do you get your status messages from and have you checked that "http://localhost:8080/crm" wasn't accessible after your error?

Comment: the status message is written in [ ] behind the Server Name under the section Servers in Eclipse. The "localhost:8080/crm" is not accessible after the error. It is weird that the server never goes in the status "Started".